# How can I detect when a textarea value changes using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

How can I detect when a textarea value changes using javascript?

Fill data into `id="yyyy"` then data `id="xxxx"` will change too, how can I `alert` when value in `id="xxxx"` change?

https://jsfiddle.net/9b6h897d/10/

please do not edit code in function `check` and `id="yyyy"`

```
<textarea id="yyyy" onkeyup="check(this.value)"></textarea>
<textarea id="xxxx" onchange="check2(this.value)" readonly></textarea>

<script>
function check(value){
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = value;
}
function check2(value){
    alert(value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could redefine the value property of the textarea element:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            //Is not changable according to OP
            function check(value){
                document.getElementById('xxxx').value = value
            };

            //Is not changable according to OP
            function check2(value){
                alert(value)
            };

            window.onload = function(){
                var tE = document.querySelector('#xxxx'); //The readonly textarea

                //Redefine the value property for the textarea
                tE._value = tE.value;
                Object.defineProperty(tE, 'value', {
                    get: function(){return this._value},
                    set: function(v){
                        console.log(this.id, ' - the value changed to: ' + v)
                        this._value = v;
                        this.setAttribute('value', v) //Setting the attribute (browser stuff);
                        check2(v)
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <textarea id = 'yyyy' onkeyup = 'check(this.value)'></textarea>
        <textarea id = 'xxxx' onchange = 'check2(this.value)' readonly></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```

console.log():
https://jsfiddle.net/mu7o1sxq/

alert():
https://jsfiddle.net/mu7o1sxq/2/

Comment: in demo i not get anyrthing T___T

Comment: @weduti sepoyuei: It is in the console. Does a man prefer an alert()?

Comment: @weduti sepoyuei: Made a second version with alert().

Comment: in secend version ,Why i not get data in `id="xxxx"` ?

Comment: @weduti sepoyuei: A man has JavaScript 'onLoad'. Put it to 'No wrap - in <head>' by clicking on the blue 'JAVASCRIPT *' label.

Answer (score 0):

you can call function inside of other function

```
<script>
function check(value){
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = value;
    check2(value);
}
function check2(value){
    alert(value);
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqud0bdn/)

try this fiddle...

Comment: function check are out of my control T___T

Answer (score 0):

Call the second function in the first not on a change event

Try this:

```
<textarea id="yyyy" onkeyup="check(this.value)"></textarea>
<textarea id="xxxx" readonly></textarea>

<script>
function check(value){
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = value;
     check2(value);//call the check2 here
}
function check2(value){
    alert(value);
}
</script>
```

or trigger the onchange event

```
<script>
function check(value){
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = value;
     document.getElementById("xxxx").onchange();
}
function check2(value){
    alert(value);
}
</script>
```

or add another event to your xxx

```
<textarea id="yyyy" onkeyup="check(this.value)" oninput="check2(this.value)"></textarea>
<textarea id="xxxx" readonly></textarea>

<script>
function check(value){
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = value;
}
function check2(value){
    alert(value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: function `check` and `id="yyyy"` out of my control T_T

Comment: get some men and control them :))

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: i can not edit function check and id="yyyy" cause it's from api.

Comment: you have a api of function, that's something new to me can you provide some example of this kind of api?

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to update value in `check()` instead call `check2()` and update the value. So remove onchange event from `id=xxxx`

EDIT : Override the `keyup` as follows and call the `inaccessible` function from that event handler

```html
<textarea id="yyyy" onkeyup="check(this.value)"></textarea>
<textarea id="xxxx" readonly></textarea>

<script>
  function check(value) {
    //your unaccessible function
  }

  document.getElementById("yyyy").addEventListener('keyup', function() {
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = this.value;
    alert(this.value);
    check(this.value)
  });
</script>
```

Comment: function `check` and `id="yyyy"` out of my control T_T

Comment: @wedutisepoyuei then you have to override the keyup as you have limitations. Please try updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MutationObserver` with configuration set to `attributes:true`, set `#xxxx` `.dataset` to `.value` of `#yyyy` at `check` function

```html
<textarea id="yyyy" onkeyup="check(this.value); document.getElementById('xxxx').dataset.value = this.value">
</textarea>
<textarea id="xxxx" data-value="" readonly></textarea>

<script>

  var x = document.getElementById("xxxx");

  function check(value) {
    document.getElementById("xxxx").value = value;
  }

  function check2(value) {
    alert(value);
  }

  var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(check2.bind(x, x.value))
  });

  observer.observe(x, {
    attributes: true
  });

</script>
```